# Filipino transferring between Narita and Haneda, do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, japan, filipino-citizens, nrt

My flight is LAX to Narita and to Haneda for my connecting flight
going to the Philippines

My questions are:

1. Do I need a transit visa?
2. Do I need to claim my luggages before proceeding to my connecting flight

Comment: These are three separate questions. 1 and 3 can maybe go together. I am editing question 2 out of the post. Please search to see if we have answered this already. If not, go ahead and post a new question.

Comment: Please tell us your Connection times. It will decide whether you Need a visa or not

Answer (score 5):

[Filipino citizens are not visa-exempt nationals](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html) according to the Japanese regulations. In addition, you need a visa if you leave the airport. This means that, for the purpose of transferring from Narita to Haneda, [you will need a Transit Visa](http://www.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/canada_e/Visa/transit.html). The Japanese embassy in the US lists [the documents required to apply](http://www.us.emb-japan.go.jp/english/html/travel_and_visa/visa/transit.html) for such a visa:

> ### Required Documents
>
> 1. Applicant's valid passport, properly signed by bearer.
> 2. VISA APPLICATION FORM TO ENTER JAPAN ([available here](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/index.html#section9)), completely filled out and signed by the applicant.
> 3. One photograph (2" x 2") attached to application form
> 4. Flight itinerary issued by travel agency or airline company (We advise you not to purchase your airline ticket until the visa is approved.)
>
> [...]
>
> 6. Visa for the next destination (if required) to be visited after Japan must already be in the passport at the time of application.
> 7. If stay in Japan exceeds one night: Proof of sufficient funds (e.g. most recent U.S. bank statement, travelers' checks or letter of guarantee from friend/relative in Japan)

Comment: This answer could be correct, depending on the Connection. A shore pass might be an option

Comment: @Crazydre What is a shore pass?

Comment: Visa-free transit provision for visa nationals making overnight connections. You get an entry stamp for 72 hours.

Comment: @Crazydre Good to know. Give me a link and I'll update the answer. :)

Comment: https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ph&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=jp&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX "Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets transiting
to a third country can obtain a Shore Pass on arrival for a
max. stay of 72 hours only if there are no connecting flights
on the same calendar day and if: For details, click here"

Comment: @Crazydre [It would seem that the shore pass and transit visa are kinda the same thing in this case.](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiI2cyZ0-rTAhUJqxoKHaV8D4oQFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hl7.org%2Fdocumentcenter%2Fpublic%2Fcalendarofevents%2Fwgm%2Fkyoto052009%2FA%2520Guide%2520to%2520Japanese%2520Visas%2520-%2520Exemption%2520of%2520Visas.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGO1-AoI7kxzHDCznbQmq9xG8MaTg)

Comment: No, a shore pass is not a visa: it's a 72-hour entry stamp for overnight transit for nationals who normally need a visa for Japan. You don't Need a visa to get this stamp. Also that website is clearly outdated, as transit passes (not the same thing as shore passes) were discontinued in 2012 (and that too wasn't a visa)

Answer (score 4):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ph&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=jp&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of onward tickets transiting
>   to a third country can obtain a Shore Pass on arrival for a
>   max. stay of 72 hours only if there are no connecting flights
>   on the same calendar day.

Which means, if you're making an overnight connection, you do **not** need a visa, and will get an entry stamp for 72 hours.

Otherwise, you **do** need a transit visa

Answer (score 4):

As of October 15, 2018, Filipino passport holders must meet 5 conditions for a Shore Pass when transiting airports in Japan. This information comes from a representative at ANA over the phone.  She read the rules.

1. transit less than 72 hrs.
2. arrival at certain airports (Narita/Haneda for eg.)
3. must have boarding pass of onward flight to 3rd country
4. must have visa for 3rd country
5. must stay in city.

No hotels are provided as a  general policy for long layovers.

Comment: And there must be no possible connection to your destination on the same day (stated in TIMATIC, the database all check-in agents use)