# Travelling from US to Philippines with layover in Japan

Tags: transit-visas, japan, layovers, filipino-citizens, us-residents

I am a permanent resident (green card holder) here in the US and holding a Philippine passport and we are going to Philippines on vacation.
We have an 8 hours lay over in Japan.

Do I need a visa to leave airport to do a little sightseeing?

Comment: Note that if you're flying into Narita then it's about an hour outside Tokyo proper.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93183/filipino-transferring-between-narita-and-haneda-do-i-need-a-transit-visa

Answer (score 1):

You can only get a shore pass if you are changing airports or your onward flight is the next calendar day. Otherwise you would need a visa to enter Japan.